# Optimisation query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this request for a long time using Google and the documentation, but it turned out bad.

```
SELECT   id,
         title,
         asin,
         sku,
         shipping1,
         manufacturing1,
         shipping2,
         manufacturing2,
         effective_date
FROM     (
                   SELECT    p.id,
                             p.title,
                             p.asin,
                             p.sku,
                             p.shipping_price      AS shipping1,
                             p.manufacturing_price AS manufacturing1,
                             eh1.amount            AS manufacturing2,
                             eh2.amount            AS shipping2,
                             eh1.effective_date
                   FROM      stores   AS s
                   LEFT JOIN products AS p
                   ON        s.id = p.store_id
                   LEFT JOIN expenses_history AS eh1
                   ON        eh1.product_id = p.id
                   AND       eh1.cost_type = 1
                   LEFT JOIN expenses_history AS eh2
                   ON        eh1.product_id = eh2.product_id
                   AND       eh1.effective_date = eh2.effective_date
                   AND       eh2.cost_type = 2
                   WHERE     s.user_id = 2
                   ORDER BY  eh1.effective_date DESC limit 18446744073709551615) AS exp
GROUP BY exp.id;I unset only_full_group_by
```

Comment: start by formatting it

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Is it because the columns are saying that they're not part of the group by clause?  Is it running too slow?  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are going to create an aggregation, it is always better to identify this and avoid sub queries.

You can execute the execution plan of MySQL, which will give a deeper detail about the creation of indexes and improvements in your query.

[using-explain MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)